# Romance or romantic?

Tags: adjectives

I've read in dictionary that **romance** can be an adjective that same as **romantic** is only adjective. So when I what to say that someone is talking about love, using specific "love" epithets, can I say

> It's **romance** language

or should I say

> It's **romantic** language

I know that languages from Roman empire (Spanish, Romanian,French etc) are called **Romance** languages, I'm curious can I apply this adjective to a person's speech?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about this:

> languages from Roman empire (Spanish, Romanian,French etc) are called Romance languages

You can use:

> romance was in the air

where romance is related to love (more or less).

You may use:

> romantic language

if you want to say that the language itself (not necessarily the meaning of the words, maybe the "music" of the language) transmits the idea of love = it can be used by people who love each other with "better" success than other languages. This use is less common.

Of course, you can speak about love in a **romance language**, but here "romance" means "Latin" and is not related to love.